# Using Android library in Kotlin multiplatform library

Tags: android, kotlin, multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have three targets commonMain/androidMain/iOSMain respectively. Because I need to access the assets in Android devices in androidMain module. I found I cannot use the Android API... The following is part of my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    buildToolsVersion("29.0.1")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(19)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
    sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
            java.srcDirs(file("src/androidMain/kotlin"))
            res.srcDirs(file("src/androidMain/res"))
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "Example"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("android")

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    }

    sourceSets["commonTest"].dependencies {
        implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
        implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
    }
}
```

How can I use Android library in androidMain? For example,

```
val inputStream = assets.open("Test.txt")
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#android-support) paragraph can help?

Comment: I updated the build.gradle.kts as above. And I still cannot use val inputStream = assets.open("Test.txt") in androidMain. What's wrong with my configuration of multiplatform?

Comment: It looks like in the example you're using, there is no way to utilize Android SDK. I think, you're trying to use [this](https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/mpp-ios-android) sample? In there, SDK is available only for the `app` module, not the `SharedCode`. Maybe [this](https://proandroiddev.com/current-issues-with-kotlin-multiplatform-and-how-to-fix-them-5ae62822a546) article could help to deal with this problem, please habe a look.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use Android SDK in androidMain in SharedCode instead of the app. I've read the article you provided but I still cannot use the Android SDK in the SharedCode... Have you tried it is possible? Cause I can access bundle for iOS using kotlin multiplatform SDK, but I cannot access for Android... it is really strange... I just want to access storage from the SharedCode.

Comment: Then try to add a dependency in the `SharedCode` script, as it is in the `app`. Also, I personally recommend you to join Kotlin Community Slack(get invite [here](http://slack.kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.165096767.1066077704.1572246741-1089074657.1560174812)). There are a lot of Kotlin/Native and MPP users, who can share more experience than I.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I join the community you recommend. By the way, I replace target jvm("android") with android(), and it seems to work but produce another issue......The IDE said "The feature multi platform projects is experimental and should be enabled explicitly". I thought the kotlin multiplatform is not so stable :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to create an AndroidManifest.xml with (library module) package name different than the (app module) package name underneath the SharedCode/src directory. And as Nagy Robi said use android() instead of jvm('android'). Please check the below references also:

- [Adding an Android Target to a Kotlin Multiplatform Project](https://medium.com/vmware-end-user-computing/adding-an-android-target-to-a-kotlin-multiplatform-project-8da72353be14)
- [Multiplatform sample](https://github.com/Kotlin/mpp-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android()` instead of `jvm('android')` to load the target from the presets.

Comment: Yes, I've changed from **jvm('android')** to **android()**, but the IDE produce another error. It said "The feature multi platform projects is experimental and should be enabled explicitly" in my android's actual class. Is there any working example in the GitHub using android API as a reference?

Comment: Try adding `enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')` to the `settings.gradle` of your project